# Як правильно перекласти словосполучення necessarily desirable

Tags: переклад, from-english, словосполучення

Перекладаю статтю з комп'ютерної графіки. 
Розумію суть речення і можу його перекласти, але не знаю як правильно це зробити для цього словосполучення - necessarily desirable.
Як зазвичай воно перекладається на українську?

Воно знаходиться в контексті такого речення:

> Відкидання невидимих поверхонь, коли об'єкт є прозорим, is also not
>   necessarily desirable.

necessarily desirable - перекласти як "обов'язково бажаним"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***`Necessarily`*** може перекладатися не тільки як ***`обов'язково`***, ***`вимушено`***, а й як ***`безумовно`***, ***`неодмінно`***.

Отже, ***`necessarily desirable`*** може бути, залежно від контексту, ***`безумовно бажаний`*** або ***`неодмінно бажаний`***, що досить милозвучно, мені здається.

Утім, слід зауважити, що **із запереченням**, як у прикладі автора, ***`necessarily`*** перекладається саме як ***`(не)обов'язково`***.

Отже, я б переклала *is also not necessarily desirable* як *теж необов'язково є бажаним*: ***Відкидання невидимих поверхонь, коли об'єкт є прозорим, теж необов'язково є бажаним***.

[Лінгвісто](http://linguisto.eu/dict/en)

[Lingvo Online](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Translate/en-uk/necessarily%20desirable)

[Мультитран](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=necessarily+desirable&l1=1)